# Creating a new column in Pandas dataframe based on set of values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some HR data and need to figure out the organisation's layer. So I have dfA with ten supervisor_IDs and dfB with a thousand employee_IDs and their supervisor_IDs. I want to create a new column which shows all the employees whose supervisors' ID can be found from dfA. How do I get there?

| Supervisor_ID |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 11 |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |

| Employee_ID | Supervisor_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1345 | 10 |
| 335 | 12 |
| 353 | 35 |
| 2134 | 47 |
| 131 | 123 |
| 123 | 19 |
| 97 | 52 |
| ... | ... |
| 987 | 10 |
| 3242 | 10 |
| 86 | 18 |
| 673 | 18 |
| 674 | 97 |
| 878 | 97 |

| Employee_ID | Supervisor_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1345 | 10 |
| 335 | 12 |
| 123 | 19 |
| ... | ... |
| 987 | 10 |
| 3242 | 10 |
| 86 | 18 |
| 673 | 18 |

```
L_0 = pd.DataFrame({"Corporate_ID": [60331], "Level": ["L0"]})
#print(L_0)

L_1 = df.loc[(df["Supervisor_ID"] == 60331)].reset_index().drop(["index"], axis=1)
L_1 = L_1.assign(Level = "L1").drop(["Supervisor_ID"], axis=1)
#print(L_1)

L_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df["Supervisor_ID"].isin(L_1["Corporate_ID"]),df["Corporate_ID"], "x"))
L_2 = L_2.set_axis(['Corporate_ID'], axis=1, inplace=False)
L_2 = L_2[L_2.Corporate_ID != "x"].assign(Level = "L2")
print(L_2)

L_3 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df["Supervisor_ID"].isin(L_2["Corporate_ID"]),df["Corporate_ID"], "x"))
L_3 = L_3.set_axis(['Corporate_ID'], axis=1, inplace=False)
#L_3 = L_3[L_3.Corporate_ID != "x"].assign(Level = "L3")
print(L_3)
```

L_2 gives correct results but L_3 gives an empty DataFrame even though it should be few hundred rows long

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get new df with data from dfA only:

```
dfC = dfB.loc[dfB['Supervisor_ID'].isin(dfA.tolist())
```

If you want to get new column with this data inside dfB:

```
dfB['dfA'] = dfB.apply(lambda x: x.Employee_ID if x.Supervisor_ID in dfA.tolist() else None, axis=1)
```